# PHP не записывает в файл

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache

Пытаюсь выполнить файл php через http запрос. Вот он:

```
    <?php

     $data = file_get_contents('php://input');

     $file_name = $_GET['name'];

     $file = fopen($file_name, 'w');

     if(substr($file_name, -4)== ".png"){
        $file_content = $data;
     }
     else{
        $file_content = iconv("WINDOWS-1251", "UTF-8", $data);
     }

     fwrite($file, $file_content);
     fclose($file);
    ?>
```

Проблема в том, что после этой операции никаких файлов не появляется (даже пустых). Но если просто выполнить операцию с записью на сервере через php, то никаких проблем. Что делать? 
P.S. Использую Apache на Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: от разных пользователей выполняется скрипт (от апача и от пользователя видимо). у одного, очевидно, нет прав на запись.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я понимаю ваш скрипт работает. 
Вполне вероятно юзеру www-data не хватает прав на запись. 
Простым решением будет дать право на запись в каталог для всех пользователей

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /путь/к/каталогу записи/
```

Comment: Помогло, спасибо

Comment: Отлично, но как я и указал это самое просто решение. 
Обратите внимание на то что написал пользователь sanmai.

Answer (score 1):

Если это ваш сервер, то лучшим решением будет не давать права всем подряд, а дать права на только доступ группе, с которой работает веб-сервер:

```
sudo chgrp www-data path/to/dir/
chmod g+rwx path/to/dir/
```

Ещё лучше будет если ваш веб-сервер будет работать под вашим ID. Такое умеют PHP-FPM и [Apache c mpm-itk](http://mpm-itk.sesse.net/). В таком случае другие сайты будут выполняться с другими ID, которые не получат доступ к вашему каталогу.

Answer (score 0):

> Пытаюсь выполнить файл php через http запрос

при этом скрипт выполняется от имени *службы вэб сервера*

> если просто выполнить операцию с записью на сервере через php, то
>   никаких проблем

при этом скрипт выполняется от имени *вашего пользователя*.

выводы:

1. скрипт сам по себе рабочий
2. у учетки вэб-сервера не достаточно прав на запись в директорию